# Python pandas: how to compare multiple value within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this

```
     cn       id      amount     date
      1     0051     45897      2021-01-14
      1     0051     78484      2021-01-15
  subtotal           124381
      2     0052    1751591     2021-01-14
      2     0052    2110386     2021-01-15
  subtotal          3861977
      3     04R3     40484      2021-01-14
      3     04R3     68598      2021-01-15
  subtotal           109082
      5     973G    3420332     2021-01-14
      5     973G    3355539     2021-01-15
  subtotal          6775871
```

There are few thousands of row but I only show 5.

What I ultimately want to do is to compare the amount from each 2021-01-14 to its subtotal.

For example, I want to write a function that returns the id(0051) if the amount(45897) in 2021-01-14
is equal to or greater than 50% of the subtotal of (124381).

In this case, only index 5, id number(973G) has the amount of 342033 that above 50% of its subtotal of 6775871.

Any idea of how I should approach this?

Comment: The `subtotal` rows can't occur inside a dataframe like that, unless you mean that's a CSV not a dataframe?

Comment: I can hep you solve it, but you haven't made any code attempt, you're [required to post your own code under SO rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @smci its a dataframe, originally it was a csv, and I have 100+ of csv like this with 1000 rows, so I would like to iterate it through dataframe. My python skill is really limited, I am only just started learning. This is actually the finally phrase, but I do not know how to approach this.

Comment: You're required to **show your own code attempt** by [SO rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). If you don't do that, questions get closed. Please edit the question to show your own code attempt. Just a few lines. We're not allowed post answers unless you do.

Answer (score 0):

You can just compare the amount with 2021-01-14 with the next amount in that column cause if it's bigger it takes more than 50 percent of subtotal

Answer (score 0):

thanks, I figured it out without touching the subtotal.

```
container=[]
for _df in df.groupby(['amount']):
    num1 = _df.iloc[0,2]
    num2 = _df.iloc[1,2]
    _df['test'] = num2 > num1
    container.append(_df)
    ch_ = pd.concat(container)
```